# UserControl with custom ItemsSource doesn't detect changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have simple `UserControl` where is defined property `ItemsSource`

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), typeof(UserControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
    new PropertyChangedCallback(UserControl1.OnItemsSourceChanged)));

public Dictionary<string, object> ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (Dictionary<string, object>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }

private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            UserControl1 control = (UserControl1)d;
            control.DisplayInControl();
        }
```

I want to make this property update dynamically, but I am wondered why `OnItemsSourceChanged` doesn't fired every time when something happend with ItemsSource. So I am upset.
I've tried [Custom ItemsSource property for a UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460034/custom-itemssource-property-for-a-usercontrol) but this doesn't help or I've written bad `newValueINotifyCollectionChanged_CollectionChanged` function

---

My control is from this post [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563862/Multi-Select-ComboBox-in-WPF)

---

My Code : 
UserControl XAML - http://pastie.org/10606317

UserControl CodeBehind - http://pastie.org/10606322

Control Usage -

```
<controls:MultiSelectComboBox SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedCategories, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="CategoriesFilter" DefaultText="Category" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories }" Style="{StaticResource FiltersDropDowns}"/>
```

---

Update : I've made small step to solution. I have next style :

```
<Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ItemsSource.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

which I apply to my control (make control disabled if no itemSource). As I update control source on click, I see that control becomes enabled, so ItemsSource aren't empty (from start it is). So problem now is just in Redrawing control content if I understand this behaviour correctly.

Comment: Define your DP in static constructor of your class.

Comment: public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty;     static YourClassName() { ItemsSourceProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), typeof(UserControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
    new PropertyChangedCallback(UserControl1.OnItemsSourceChanged))); }

Comment: @AnjumSKhan - after I tried it, i got exception - `Additional information: 'ItemsSource' property was already registered by 'UserControl1'.`

Comment: upload  your code where you are using it.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan, please check update. Hope this is fine for you

Comment: When you say "something happend with ItemsSource" are you referring to an item added or removed from the source?  Or are looking for an event to fire whenever an item in the source is changed?  An [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) as mentioned in the answers below should already handle the former.

Comment: @MikeGuthrie, what I do with ItemsSource - it is `Clear` and `Add`. I've tried with ObservableCollection - but still on UI content of my control is unchanged

Comment: @demo I ran your code, and OnItemsSourceChanged function is executing as expected.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan The problem isn't really the `OnItemsSourceChanged`, rather that the collection he's binding is ultimately entirely different than the one used by the rendered control -- see my answer, below, and check [the code-behind link](http://pastie.org/10606322), line 164.  Also, mind deleting some comments to remove the clutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the problem is that you are building a new `ItemsSource` for the `ComboBox` control within your custom `UserControl`, and that you are expecting that `MultiSelectCombo.ItemsSource` to stay synced with your `UserControl1.ItemsSource`.  This can't happen when simply binding a `Dictionary`, and it won't happen even when binding an `ObservableCollection` -- unless you explicitly handle it.

To accomplish what you are after, first you will need `ItemsSource` of your custom control to be of a type that does notify us of collection changes, such as the [`ObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) (which I'll use for this example, as you've done in your links above).  Then, you'll need to update the `ItemsSource` of your `ComboBox` within your control, to keep them in sync.

```
private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (MultiSelectComboBox)d;

    // Since we have to listen for changes to keep items synced, first check if there is an active listener to clean up.
    if (e.OldValue != null)
    {
        ((ObservableCollection<Node>)e.OldValue).CollectionChanged -= OnItemsSource_CollectionChanged;
    }

    // Now initialize with our new source.
    if (e.NewValue != null)
    {
        ((ObservableCollection<Node>)e.NewValue).CollectionChanged += OnItemsSource_CollectionChanged;
        control.DisplayInControl();
    }
}

private void OnItemsSource_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayInControl();
}
```

Now, that said, the solution above is for a more generic case, where you might need to do something with the `ItemsSource` given to your custom control before passing it onto your `MultiSelectCombo.ItemsSource`.  In your current case, however, you are simply building a collection of `Node` to exactly match the given collection of `Node`.  If that's guaranteed to be the case, your solution can be much, much simpler:

```
private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (MultiSelectComboBox)d;
    control.MultiSelectCombo.ItemsSource = (IEnumerable)e.NewValue;
}
```

Just let the wrapped `ComboBox` use the `ItemsSource` given to your custom control.

Comment: `((ObservableCollection<Node>)e.OldValue).CollectionChanged += OnItemsSource_CollectionChanged;` should here be `e.NewValue` ?

Comment: I've tried "simpler" sample, but this doesn't solve my problem. Don't know why...

Comment: @demo Yeah, sorry, that was an error from copy-paste.  You are right, should be `e.NewValue`.  Does either solution solve your issue?  Seems like you should be able to just pass along the `ItemsSource` of `UserControl` to `ComboBox` and still have it work.  You are sure that items are added to the correct source instance?

Comment: Thank you, Mike. Your answer help me :). Problem was in way, how I modify my `ObservableCollection`. Firstly I've added elements like `Types.Add(element)` in loop. But now I've tried next `Types = new ObservableCollection<Node>(list)` where list is container for elements that I've added one by one. So now it works. Is it ok to do like this?

Comment: @demo That's fine to do to initialize the control, so long as you understand that adding elements to `list` after your `Types = new ObservableCollection<Node>(list)` call are not going to include them in the rendered conrol.

Comment: Well, I've found one problem with everytime initializing - It can't save checked elements on previous step

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dictionary as your data type, and you add or remove a value from the dictionary, then your property did not actually change.  This event will only fire if you have actually set this property to reference a different dictionary.

If you need wpf to automatically detect if an item is added or removed from the dictionary, you should use an ObservableCollection.

Comment: I've tried `ObservableCollection` but still `ItemsSource` of my control is the same

Comment: Just for clarification, are you trying to update your control when you add or remove an item?

Comment: Also, would it be possible to post the xaml for your user control at the bottom of your question?  Maybe that would clarify what you need to do to solve this problem.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563862/Multi-Select-ComboBox-in-WPF My control is from this post

Answer (score 1):

1. Replace Dictionary with ObservableCollection, Dictionary won't fire the propertyChanged event when add, update, delete an item.
2. Write your own Dictionary to fire the propertychanged event manually.

Comment: I've tried ObservableCollection but still ItemsSource of my control is the same