# implementing ItemsSource property in uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, itemssource

I'm going to create a UserControl for a specific purpose. I need to bind a IEnumerable object to it, so I need to Implement ItemsSource property.

I found following answer for WPF:
[Custom ItemsSource property for a UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460034/custom-itemssource-property-for-a-usercontrol/)

As noticed on a comment `newValueINotifyCollectionChanged` is always null.
What should I do to make this working?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @Stefan Yes. I Tried, It's always null

Comment: Is `oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged` always null as well? And how are you setting the `ItemSource` property? You should set it with a collection which implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`

Comment: Yes, actually the element doesn't have value! I have a type named `category` & `List<category>` is what I set on ItemsSource

Comment: Try to make the list a `ObservableCollection<catagory>`, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hey tnx, It worked successfully! but what's the difference really?
I always use `List<>` to bind my arrays to a listview or such elements

Comment: Well, the main difference is that it implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface, which according to the spec's `Notifies listeners of dynamic changes, such as when an item is added and removed or the whole list is cleared.` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx). If you are using lists, binding a new list would work, but in case you add a single element after the bind, the ui won't be updated.

Comment: Yes, there are some options to do that, but it's mostly a matter of choice. Perhaps you want two combo boxes, or nested items. In the latter you'll need find a way to visualize it. Maybe a group by, some indent `--` 's, or maybe there are some components at github that will do that trick.

Comment: ok, really thanks man